# Loop Json Properties in C#

Tags: c#, json

I receive the following JSON string. It is part of the specifications of products. The data represents the Header ("General") and the items within in Key value pairs.

I dont want to hard code any properties such as general, Display Features and should be able to

1. Retrieve the Header
2. Iterate on the key value pair.

So Far I have the following code

```
foreach (var SpecList in objAPIProduct.categorySpecificInfoV1.specificationList)
{     
    foreach(dynamic  SpecItem in SpecList.General)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SpecItem.key);
        Console.WriteLine(SpecItem.value[0]);
    }    
}
```

I want to get rid of the "General" Property that I have hardcoded  in the inner foreach loop and make the loop generic for all properties.
Here is the Json that I have

```
{
    "General": [{
        "key": "Sales Package",
        "value": ["Laptop, Power Adapter, Warranty Document"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Model Number",
        "value": ["3558"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Part Number",
        "value": ["Z565103UIN9"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Model Name",
        "value": ["Inspiron 15"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Series",
        "value": ["Inspiron"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Color",
        "value": ["Black"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Type",
        "value": ["Notebook"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Suitable For",
        "value": ["Everyday Use"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Battery Backup",
        "value": ["Upto 3.5 hours"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Battery Cell",
        "value": ["4 cell"]
    }]
},
{
    "Processor and Memory Features": [{
        "key": "Processor Brand",
        "value": ["Intel"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Processor Name",
        "value": ["Core i3"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Graphic Processor",
        "value": ["Intel HD Graphics 5500"]
    },
    {
        "key": "SSD",
        "value": ["No"]
    },
    {
        "key": "RAM",
        "value": ["4 GB"]
    },
    {
        "key": "RAM Type",
        "value": ["DDR3"]
    },
    {
        "key": "HDD Capacity",
        "value": ["500 GB"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Processor Variant",
        "value": ["5005U"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Clock Speed",
        "value": ["2 GHz"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Memory Slots",
        "value": ["1 Slot"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Expandable Memory",
        "value": ["Upto 4 GB"]
    },
    {
        "key": "RAM Frequency",
        "value": ["1600 MHz"]
    },
    {
        "key": "Cache",
        "value": ["3 MB"]
    },
    {
        "key": "RPM",
        "value": ["5400"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: use `JSON.Net` and simply [Deserialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm).

Comment: It is deserialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a lot of options, I found that it is not possible to get the "Name" of the property when we use Json.Net or JavascriptSerialiser.

Finally, I used the help of this thread -

[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

wherein the person has suggested using System.Web.Helpers and it works perfect in my case.

Here is my final code:
 dynamic objAPIProduct= Json.Decode(json);

```
List<ProductSpecification> objProductSpecificationList = new List<ProductSpecification>();
            ProductSpecification objProductSpecification;

            foreach (var SpecListCategoryList in objAPIProduct.categorySpecificInfoV1.specificationList)
            {
               foreach (var SpecCategory in SpecListCategoryList)
                {

                    DynamicJsonArray objListitems = SpecCategory.Value;

                    for  (int  i = 0; i < objListitems.Length; i++)
                     {
                    objProductSpecification = new ProductSpecification();
                    objProductSpecification.SpecificationHead = SpecCategory.Key;
                    objProductSpecification.SpecificationKey = objListitems[i].key;
                    objProductSpecification.SpecificationValue = objListitems[i].value[0];
                    objProductSpecificationList.Add(objProductSpecification);
                     }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

On site [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) you can generate classes for your JSON.

```
public class General
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public List<string> value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<General> General { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize JSON to it using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

And:

```
foreach(General g in ro.General)
{
    string k = g.key;
}
```

Comment: The Json has been deserialised using JavascriptSerializer. Here is that part of code -

 var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });

                 model = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

In my code in the original post, it is working - But I have kind of "hard coded" the property "General" -- which I do not want to. As the property names would keep changing as per the product data.

Comment: In the inner loop - 
foreach(dynamic  SpecItem in SpecList.General)
I want to get rid of the .General here

Comment: @John JSON.NET is better, even Microsoft use JSON.NET in MVC. If you can change JavascriptSerializer  to JSON.NET

Comment: Well, I agree. But this one is working just fine.And honestly, I dont really want to tinker with existing code. I have just to deal with that part of getting the product specifications and to make sure that I do not hard code anything. The property in the json is what is the pain area. Please bear in mind, that the json I say is already deserialise.

Comment: @John I see your point. Then you must look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex.aspx and implement own logic.

Comment: Yes, I have been playing around with the TrySetIndex - no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your SpecList class like this

```
public class SpecList : Dictionary<string, List<SpecItem>>
{
}
```

From then you will be able to access your general property like this

```
foreach (var SpecList in    objAPIProduct.categorySpecificInfoV1.specificationList)
{
    foreach(var key in SpecList.Keys)
    {
        foreach(var SpecItem in SpecList[key])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(SpecItem.key);
            Console.WriteLine(SpecItem.value[0]);
        }    
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to use the word "General", instead can I somehow get it using the index. Maybe something like [code] var general = SpecList[0] [/code] However this does not work

Comment: It gives a NULL error on SpecList.Keys in the second foreach - even when SpecList in the immediate window shows - {General:[key:"Model Number",value:["E484"]},key:"Model Name",value:["Canvas 6 Pro"]},key:"Color",value:["Black"]},key:"Browse Type",value:["Smartphones"]},key:"SIM Type",value:["Dual Sim"]},key:"Operating System",value:["Android"]},key:"Operating System Version Name",value:["Lollipop"]},key:"Operating System Version Number",value:["5.1"]},key:"Internal Storage",value:["16 GB"]},key:"RAM",value:["4 GB"]},key:" ....

Comment: What if you replace SpecList directly with Dictionary<string, List<SpecItem>> in your code/mapping ?

Comment: tried it - Cannot convert type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<SpecItem>>' - didnt work :(

Comment: Use var instead of dynamic

Comment: Nopes, I wasnt able to get it to work even with var, dynamic - I am still getting the same message. I am now looking at string manipulation...